# Is there a `printk()` function supporting `va_list`?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm currently writing a Linux kernel module, and I need to handle `va_list` in one of my functions, which looks like:

```
void blah(int flag, va_list va) {
    ...
    if (flag & BLAH_1) {
        ...
        printk(... va here ...); // where I need the printk() with va_list support
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

So I need a `printk()`-like function which supports varargs. Like `vprintf()` to `printf()`.

I Google'd for `vprintk`, but had no luck finding it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use [vsnprintf()](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/teaching/lectures/opsys/10_11/docs/kernelAPI/r1578.html) to format a `va_list` into a buffer, and pass that buffer to `printk()`.

However, a [`vprintk()` function seems to exist in the kernel](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/ident/vprintk).

Comment: Oh, thanks! Never realized that I could use `vsnprintf()`, though I need to take care of the buffer size :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible and the function you have to use is ***vprintk***(format string, va_list);
You dont have to think of the buffer size. Just simply use it as of printk.